# AWS API Gateway Model Json Schema With Varying Properties

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am developing an API on the AWS API gateway. I am using the model validation option to validate the JSON payload. I have request json with varying/dynamic keys like:

```
{
 "devJson":{
  "cb001": 12,
  "cb002": 32,
  .
  .
  .
  .
  "cb078": 45
 }
}
```

It is very tedious if I have to write all properties in the model schema like this:

```
    "devJson": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "cb001": { "type": "number" },
        "cb002": { "type": "number" },
        .
        .
        .
        .
        "cb100": { "type": "number" }
       }
    }
```

Is there any way I can just mention the type of the devJson as json? Like:

```
"devJson": {
 "type": "json"
}
```

Could someone help me in suggesting a solution here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could someone help me on how to specify the json schema in such scenarios?